# How export symetric AES key cryptoapi

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, cryptoapi

I have some problem. I need generate and export symmetric key with use CryptoAPI.

```
     if(CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv_AES, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES,  0))
    {
        _tprintf(
            TEXT("A cryptographic provider has been acquired. \n"));
    }
    else
    {
            DWORD d = GetLastError();
            std::cout<<"";
            return -1;
    }

    if (!CryptGenKey(hCryptProv_AES,CALG_AES_256,CRYPT_EXPORTABLE,&hSessionKey_AES))
        {
            DWORD d = GetLastError();
            std::cout<<"";
            return -1;
        }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"OK";
    }

    // Export key
   BYTE keybuf[ 1024 ], buffer[ 1024 ];
   DWORD i, keylen = sizeof( buffer );

    struct ekb
   {
       PUBLICKEYSTRUC  hdr;
       ALG_ID                 algId;
       BYTE                    key[1];
   } *encKey = (struct ekb *)buffer;

    bool bbb = CryptExportKey(hSessionKey_AES, NULL, SIMPLEBLOB, 0, (BYTE *)encKey, &keylen);
    DWORD f = GetLastError();
```

but don't can take AES key.
How I can fix this trouble, please help. How I can get AES key??

UPDATE
For example I use next code and can get public RSA key.

```
char * base_txt = "Test text";
    char * enc_text = "";


     if(CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv_RSA, NULL, MS_ENHANCED_PROV , PROV_RSA_FULL,  0))
    {
        _tprintf(
            TEXT("A cryptographic provider has been acquired. \n"));
    }
    else
    {
            DWORD d = GetLastError();
            std::cout<<"";
            return -1;
    }

    if (!CryptGenKey(hCryptProv_RSA,AT_KEYEXCHANGE,1024<<16,&hSessionKey))
        {
            DWORD d = GetLastError();
            std::cout<<"";
            return -1;
        }

    RSAPubKey1024 key; 
    DWORD dwLen=sizeof(RSAPubKey1024);



    // Export key
    bool bb = CryptExportKey(hSessionKey,NULL,PUBLICKEYBLOB,0,(BYTE *)&key,&dwLen);
```

**UPDATE 2**
After export I import key and try encrypt and decrypt

```
HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv_AES22;
    if (CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv_AES22, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, 0))
    {
        printf("A cryptographic provider has been acquired.\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    int iii =  CryptImportKey(hCryptProv_AES22,(BYTE *)&exportKey_AES,keylen,NULL,NULL,&hSessionKey_AES2);

    if(CryptSetKeyParam(hSessionKey_AES2,KP_IV, exportKey_AES, 0))
    {
        BYTE encryptedMessage[1024];
        const char * message = "Decryption Works -- using multiple blocks";
        BYTE messageLen = (BYTE)strlen(message);
        memcpy(encryptedMessage, message, messageLen);
        DWORD encryptedMessageLen = messageLen;
        CryptEncrypt(hSessionKey_AES2, NULL, TRUE, 0, encryptedMessage, &encryptedMessageLen, sizeof(encryptedMessage));    
        CryptDecrypt(hSessionKey_AES2,NULL,TRUE,0,encryptedMessage, &encryptedMessageLen);

    }
```

Comment: Why do you think you can not bet AES key? Does `CryptExportKey` return `FALSE`? If yes, what error code does `GetLastError` give?

Comment: return FALSE && error code f = 2148073485

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CryptExportKey` has a limitation. It **requires** to export non-public keys in encrypted form. When you export public part or RSA key pair, it is OK to make the 2nd `CryptExportKey` parameter `NULL` and export key in unencrypted form. However, you can not do the same for symmetric key that **must** specify non-null `hExpKey` parameter.
If you specify `hExpKey` parameter, your code works, see example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Create AES key
    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv_AES;
    if (CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv_AES, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, 0))
    {
        printf("A cryptographic provider has been acquired.\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    HCRYPTKEY hSessionKey_AES;
    if (!CryptGenKey(hCryptProv_AES, CALG_AES_256, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hSessionKey_AES))
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    // Create RSA key to encrypt AES one
    HCRYPTKEY hSessionKey;
    if (!CryptGenKey(hCryptProv_AES, AT_KEYEXCHANGE, 1024 << 16, &hSessionKey))
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    // Export key
    DWORD keylen;
    BOOL ok = CryptExportKey(hSessionKey_AES, hSessionKey, SIMPLEBLOB, 0, NULL, &keylen);
    if (ok == FALSE)
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    BYTE *encKey = (BYTE *)malloc(keylen);
    ok = CryptExportKey(hSessionKey_AES, hSessionKey, SIMPLEBLOB, 0, encKey, &keylen);
    if (ok == FALSE)
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("A cryptographic key export succeeded.\r\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to do key exchange (lets say, if you want that Alice send to Bob her AES key), you have to do following steps:

1. Bob generates RSA key and sends its public part to Alice. See, Bob starts, not Alice!
2. Bob sends his key public part to Alice.
3. Alice generates AES key.
4. Alice encrypts AES key with Bob's public key.
5. Alice sends the AES key to Bob.
6. Bob uses his private key to decrypt AES key (i. e. import it with `CryptImportKey`). When you import the key, you set `hPubKey` parameter to non-NULL value, actually you set it to Bob's key handle, otherwise import will fail, because the AES key in encrypted.

Comment: ok, but where I want to import need use only
int iii =  CryptImportKey(hCryptProv_AES,(BYTE *)&exportKey_AES,keylen,NULL,NULL,&new_session_key); ?

Comment: I added explanation how to exchange keys to the answer.